# Whats wrong in my php code?

Tags: php, arrays

I am  trying to find lowest of odd numbers in an array.

Here is my code:

```
$a=array(81,10,6,71,13,61,8,16,0,9,12);
$b=count($a);
for($i=0;$i<$b;$i++)
{
    if($a[$i]/2!=0)
    {
        $flag=0;

        for($j=0;$j<$b;$j++)
        {
            if($a[$j]<=$a[$i] and $a[$j]/2!=0)
            {
                $a[$i]=$a[$j];
                $flag=1;        
            }
        }

        if($flag==1)
        {
            echo('lowest odd number is'.$a[$i]);
        }

        break;
    }

    break;
}
```

I am not looking for new logic I am just trying to find an error in the above code. Why is it not working?

Comment: "not working" is never a sufficient explanation of a problem. what are you expecting it to do and what is it doing instead?

Comment: try sorting your array and with a loop return the first nummer odd number.

Comment: try this code http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/qu0-e9s

Comment: thanks for your good reply...algorhythm,,, its working.. god bless you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want mod (`%`) instead of division (`/`), as in

```
if($a[$i]%2!=0)
```

Comment: the same here $a[$j]/2!=0